# Awkwardness in the world

Tags: buddha, tipitaka, sangha, love, buddhist

Here is my question:

> How does a lay Buddhist respond to awkwardness and how does a monk
>   respond to awkwardness such as dropping something while ordaining or
>   falling on the floor?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the buddhist way to deal with awkwardness is similar to any emotion: Accept it, don't act on it, and go on with life.

Unless it's awkward in a precept-breaking way. If so, refer to the vinaya.